# expo install react-native-svg "error Running this command will add the dependency to the workspace root rather than the workspace itself..."

Tags: react-native, svg, expo, yarnpkg

I'm using Expo CLI. I want to use SVG in React Native. So, I follow an instruction from here https://github.com/react-native-svg/react-native-svg. But when I installed `expo install react-native-svg` I received the following error:

```
expo install react-native-svg 
    > yarn add react-native-svg
    yarn add v1.22.11
    info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this command.
    error Running this command will add the dependency to the workspace root rather than the workspace itself, which might not be what you want - if you really meant it, make it explicit by running this command again with the -W flag (or --ignore-workspace-root-check).
    yarnpkg exited with non-zero code: 1
    Error: yarnpkg exited with non-zero code: 1
        at ChildProcess.completionListener (C:\Users\85620\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\spawn-async\src\spawnAsync.ts:65:13)
        at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:482:26)
        at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:375:28)
        at ChildProcess.cp.emit (C:\Users\85620\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:34:29)
        at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1055:16)
        at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:288:5)
        ...
        at Object.spawnAsync [as default] (C:\Users\85620\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\spawn-async\src\spawnAsync.ts:26:19)
        at YarnPackageManager._runAsync (C:\Users\85620\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\package-manager\src\NodePackageManagers.ts:309:31)
        at YarnPackageManager.addAsync (C:\Users\85620\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\package-manager\src\NodePackageManagers.ts:258:16)
        at actionAsync (C:\Users\85620\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\src\commands\installAsync.ts:55:12)
```

[Screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q9Sdt.png)

And when I tried this command `yarn add react-native-svg`, I received this error

```
yarn add react-native-svg
error Running this command will add the dependency to the workspace root rather than the workspace itself, which might not be what you want - if you really meant it, make it explicit by running this command again with the -W flag (or --ignore-workspace-root-check).
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this command.
```

[Screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uhtJl.png)

Any suggestion? I'm new to Expo and React Native.

Comment: Welcome! Please post the error texts as text (in citation format), not as images.

Comment: Edited, please check.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use expo command

```
expo install react-native-svg
```

Comment: Actually, I enter this line "expo install react-native-svg" before. After that this line "yarn add react-native-svg" automatically comes below and followed by the error code above as you can see in the screenshot link. I've edited the post, please check the screenshot link.

Answer (score 0):

According to this topic [why does yarn warn when adding a dependency to the root workspaces package.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51235261/why-does-yarn-warn-when-adding-a-dependency-to-the-root-workspaces-package-json/53558779), now I can install it with the following command.

```
yarn workspace mobile-app add react-native-svg
```